# What is "plaice" in the US? Would love a good fish and chips

Tags: american-english, british-english, terminology

When we went to the market, at the fisherman's counter we asked for *plaice* with which we would make fish and chips. Now here in the States when we ask for *plaice*, they don't understand what we mean. Can anyone tell me with confidence what *plaice* is called in the northeastern United States?

Comment: I had the same problem. When I moved back to the United States from Spain, I had been used to eating *merluza*. Looking up the translation, I found it is supposed to mean *plaice* -- which I had never heard of. That's because there is no such fish that grows in the United States' nearby coastal waters, nor is that fish normally sold here.

Comment: I live in the northeast US and I had never heard of *plaice* before this question. If I get fish and chips at all, it's probably in the summer when visiting Cape Cod, and one of the [fish types listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_and_chips#Choice_of_fish) is used, like cod or haddock.

Comment: Yes, there had to be a reason why they named it Cape Cod and not Cape Plaice. Have you tried using English ale in the batter!

Comment: My wife and I were pleasantly surprised with the **tilapia** we ate in the SW US last year. It tasted like a cross between cod and plaice. I don't know whether it's available in the NE - or even if that name would refer to the same species there.

Comment: Tilapia is good stuff -- freshwater, and fast growing so it doesn't hang around absorbing nasties from the environment.

Comment: I know at the Chip Chop in NYC (a pretty famous restaurant) you can actually order "Plaice & Chips" (you can also order Cod or Haddock). The Chip Chop attempts to be at least somewhat authentically British though -- other than at that restaurant I've never heard the term "plaice" in the United States.

Comment: @tchrist, I believe _merluza_ is also the fish known in English as _hake_. However, like plaice, hake isn't commonly sold in any region of the USA where I have lived, so this is no help at the supermarket.

Answer (score 6):

Plaice is one variety of [flatfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatfish), related to sole, halibut, and flounder. It is not commercially available in the US so its name is rarely heard there.

In the US, when you find 'fish and chips' (purely a British cultural import) is usually made with cod, whitefish, or haddock, the same is in the UK. Fish and chips made with plaice is unknown in the US.

Answer (score 5):

Try looking it up in Wikipedia. Plaice, Pleuronectes platessa, is a European fish that is related to an American fish of the same family, which they've overfished. Many nations have different names for the same fish, though some are only related species. The question has a fundamental flaw in that you should have asked for cod!

Comment: Pacific cod isn't bad (never eat the toxic stunted remains of the noble species in Europe) but Haddock is popular at least on the west coast

Answer (score 5):

*Plaice* is "sole", a flat fish, and *merluza* is "hake". I am quite certain, as a Canadian who lives in Spain, a biologist and a fish-and-chips connoisseur.

Comment: An expert answer on the internet!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure, despite having lived in US for five years, but why not try *sole* or *flounder*.  They belong to the same family.

Comment: They appear to be called "Dab" as well: Sole in the US is a more catchall term, often used for Plaice

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_and_chips#Choice_of_fish) says about the choice of fish in fish and chips:

> In the United States, the type of fish used depends on availability in a given region. Some common types are cod, halibut, flounder, tilapia or, in New England, Atlantic cod or haddock. Salmon is growing common on the West Coast, while freshwater catfish is most commonly used in the Southeast.

Cod is one of the most common for fish and chips, but you may wish to avoid it due to [overfishing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collapse_of_the_Atlantic_northwest_cod_fishery).

Answer (score 2):

No one's really answered the question yet. Plaice is called "plaice" here in the US. It's just very seldom offered. I think I've seen it in ingredient lists.

Comment: As stated in Wikipedia, the American plaice is called flounder, Hippoglossoides platessoides, or dab and has been overfished, so it is rarely available in the US, but cod, the true fish of fish 'n' chips, is available, although it suffers a similar plight.

Answer (score 2):

Thirty years ago, when I visited my (originally English) relatives in California, they told me with delight that they had found somewhere that served plaice, and described it as "North Sea flounder".

Answer (score 2):

As you are making your own, probably the closest taste to plaice is halibut, but that’s pretty pricey when you can get it fresh.  Depending on where you are, try flounder: it’s similar and around here is pretty reasonably priced.  Personally, I find tilapia tasteless.

If you try ordering fish and chips, it’s pretty rare to have a choice of fish, and they almost never have malt vinegar!

Good luck, and so nice to hear that someone is making fish and chips at home!

Comment: I know, it is not Seasoned Advice.SE, but I just wanted to point out, that it is the whole selling point of tilapia — that it is not too “fishy”, but one can still season it nicely (I had great success just sautéing some onions, and frying tilapia fillet with nothing but salt and pepper on top of them — magnifique!).

Answer (score 1):

American law is unfortunately not very scientific in its requirements for fish names. For example, the fish commonly sold on the West Coast as "Pacific snapper", and even "Pacific red snapper" is not a near relative of the "red snapper" sold in the East. The Atlantic fish is much better eating. Whatever rules there are about which fish may be labeled "sole", "snapper", and "cod" are [often](http://www.sfgate.com/science/article/Mislabeled-fish-a-widespread-problem-4295946.php) violated.

On the other hand, we may have varieties that work well in fish-and-chips under our own names. I suggest you try whatever your market calls "flounder". If you are being paid in pounds, with the exchange favorable these days, you could try Alaskan halibut fillets, but fresh they were $20/lb last I looked.

Comment: And that delicious Chilean Sea Bass? Real name is the not-so-appetising "Patagonian Toothfish".